# What is the "Immortal Radar" range?

Tags: highlander, highlander-franchise

Is there a canon-supported estimate on how far an Immortal can "sense" the presence of another Immortal?

Comment: It can vary depending on circumstances.  In the version of Highlander I've got (apparently a director's cut), there's a scene of Connor and Brenda at the zoo, and The Kurgan is visible about 20 feet away watching them, but Connor is paying attention to Brenda and doesn't notice.

Comment: A microwave oven that never breaks down? 8-)}

Comment: [Range of Plot](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TravelingAtTheSpeedOfPlot) -- WARNING -- TvTropes link; you could lose hours if you follow it...

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you consider **canon**. In the movies it is never discussed in depth to give a range.  The show implies that it can depend on 3 factors, age of the Immortal, the number of Quickenings they have had, and an x factor that sometimes is explained as either a spiritual or meditative suppression ability.  This can limit the sense range from 20 feet, as seen when Duncan met Methos, or as much as 100 yards.