# How did the Kurgan know that Connor MacLeod was a fellow immortal?

Tags: highlander-franchise, highlander

The "immortal radar" [mentioned in other questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19734/what-is-the-immortal-radar-range) does not explain how the Kurgan knew Connor MacLeod was immortal.

- He was far away on the other side of a valley before the 1536 battle against the MacLeod clan
- He knew that Connor was among the hundreds of people in the battle
- He also knew it was Connor **well before the battle began** because he made a pact with the chieftain of the Fraser clan that *only he could kill Connor*.

**So how did the Kurgan know Connor MacLeod was immortal?**

Comment: It's a good question in its own right and you don't need to justify asking it :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was addressed in [*Highlander Origins: Kurgan #2*](https://highlander.fandom.com/wiki/Highlander_Origins:_Kurgan#2). The Kurgan had a series of *prophetic dreams* that he would face MacLeod in the far future and that Macleod would kill him. The Kurgan sought to subvert this by finding MacLeod and killing him as a pre-Immortal.

[image]

Over time the dreams become more specific, showing him Connor's full name, what he looks like and, crucially, that he was a member of the Scottish clan MacLeod, providing him with a rough location.

[image]

From that point onwards, it was simply a matter of time before he could find an opportunity to get close to him without risking an execution.

Comment: That just says his dream-opponent has a sword with the name MacLeod on the hilt. The dream doesn't give a first name. Just because the sword has a name doesn't mean that is the name of the sword's owner. Do you have more specific info than a dream sword with a name?

Comment: @RichS - I've edited. The dreams were extremely specific. They stopped short of providing Connor's Social Security Number and shoe size, but that's about it.