# Why didn't the immortals sense the presence of the Kurgan nearby?

Tags: highlander-franchise, highlander

In *Highlander*, the Kurgan sneak-attacks his victims several times.

- He spies on Brenda and Connor when they visit the zoo. He was within 6 meters of Connor MacLeod at the zoo.
- He sneak attacks Connor MacLeod after he leaves a bar to follow Brenda. He got to within a meter or two of MacLeod. He is close enough to be within striking distance.
- He hides within the Silvercup Studio sign to sneak attack Connor MacLeod again. He is again close enough to be within striking distance.

This is at odds of immortals having a "[radar-like awareness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19734/what-is-the-immortal-radar-range)" of other immortals nearby.

Why do other immortals not sense the Kurgan when he was is close enough to kill them?

Comment: This answer https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19734/what-is-the-immortal-radar-range?rq=1 makes it sound like there's examples of immortals with some sort of ability to suppress their presence on the immortal radar.

Answer (score 7):

I’m not aware of them knowing *where* other immortals are (at least not in the first movie), and I don’t remember the zoo scene (that’s only in the European version, it seems). In the other two instances, Connor knows that the Kurgan is near but not exactly where he is. As far as I can tell from the original movie, that’s all that they can apparently do.